# How can I check if an SQL result contains a newline character?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a varchar column that contains the string `lol\ncats`, however, in SQL Management Studio it shows up as `lol cats`.

How can I check if the `\n` is there or not?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE your_column LIKE '%' + CHAR(10) + '%'
```

Or...

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), your_column) > 0
```

Answer (score 53):

Use `char(13)` for `'\r'` and `char(10)` for `'\n'`

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE your_column LIKE '%' + CHAR(10) + '%'
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE your_column LIKE '%' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + '%'
```

Comment: +1 for noting the characters that `CHAR(10)` and `CHAR(13)` correspond to.

Answer (score 16):

For any fellow MySQL users who end up here:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE your_column LIKE CONCAT('%', CHAR(10), '%')
```

Comment: Equally, this solution is also valid in SQL 2012+

Answer (score 5):

For me, the following worked just fine in both MySQL Workbench & HeidiSQL (working with MySQL) without having to use the `char()` variation of `\n`:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE field_name LIKE '%\n%'
```

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle, try the below command

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE field_name LIKE ('%'||chr(10)||'%');
```

Comment: this is the only one that worked for me! u might wanna change the `chr` to `char` in the code example, cuz `chr` isnt a thing, and i had to do `char` for it to work

Comment: ^^^ also works in Postgres, i.e.:
```LIKE ('%'||chr(10)||'%')```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE PATINDEX('%' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + '%', Column) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn REGEXP "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select cc.columnname,right(cc.columnname,1),ASCII(right(cc.columnname,1)) ,cc.*
from table_name cc where 
ASCII(right(cc.columnname,1)) = 13
```

here

- `cc.columnname` =>  Column name is column where you want to fine new
  line or Carriage return.
- `right(cc.columnname,1)` => this will show only one char what is there
  at the end. usually it display only blank
- `ASCII(right(cc.columnname,1))` => here we get Acii value of that not
  printable value.

by seeing this ascii value we can conclude which item it is. Example , if this acsci value is 13 then Carriage return , if it is 10 then NEw line  we have to use this to filter that record

- `cc.*` => this gives all the values from the table ( display purpose)
- `where  ASCII(right(cc.columnname,1)) = 13` => here i found all the
  values are 13 asci value so filtering ascii value 13

it is working for me .

Answer (score 0):

For any fellow Redshift users who end up here:

```
select * from your_table where your_column ~ '[\r\n]+'
```