# T-SQL - Show newline constant in results

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, newline, ssms

I've been having trouble with a query on a database I'm working with. The database would for instance return 18 results, and the LINQ query in the parent .NET project, would return 27 results. I've found this is down to newlines, as the database was created out of an Excel document.

Is there a way in SQL Server Manangement Studio to show these new line characters in the cells of the results of a query. Just something like printing "\n" on the end of all cells that have this new line character?

I've tried the following query `WHERE` statements but with no joy:-

```
AND (FieldName like '%Text String%' + CHAR(10))
AND (FieldName like '%Text String%' + CHAR(13))
AND (FieldName like CHAR(10) + '%Text String%' + CHAR(10))
AND (FieldName like CHAR(13) + '%Text String%' + CHAR(13))
AND (FieldName like CHAR(10) + '%Text String%')
AND (FieldName like CHAR(13) + '%Text String%')
```

as I read [How can I check if an SQL result contains a newline character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872270/how-can-i-check-if-an-sql-result-contains-a-newline-character) with these CHAR(10) and CHAR(13) as ways of testing if there is a new line in the field.

Is there a way to print these new lines in the fields of the results of the query?

**UPDATE**
As an example:-

The following returns 0 results:-

`AND (DrillType = 'Plain Bore')`

but the following returns 5 results:-

`AND (L3Bore = 'Plain Bore
  ')`

Note, the closing quote and bracket on a new line. Does this make any sense as to why this would be happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you get a different result from Linq as you do from SSMS, then the two queries aren't the same so how would "showing newline" help?

Comment: SQL doesn't care about newlines. If a raw SQL query and a LINQ query return different data it's because they are different queries. Please post the queries. Trying to do a `LIKE '%x%'` though is a **very** bad idea because it forces a scan of the entire table. It would be better to clean the data. BTW, why append newlines at all, when `%Text String%` will return everything, newlines or not?

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear. We copied in data from Excel to the database, and as a result, we seem to have copied in newline characters which stop some results coming back in the query. I've checked by editing one of the affected rows and overwriting it with the same string of text, and it then is retrieved in the query. It's as if there is some hidden character in each field meaning the query is not a match?

Comment: See update above for an example of whats going on.

Comment: @MikeUpjohn is it correct that unsuccessful and successful queries in your example refer different column?

Comment: Replace all `AND` in your where condition to `OR` :) And you can check with `Fieldname like '%' +  char(10) + '%' OR Fieldname like '%' +  char(13) + '%'` - this way you find all newlines independent of position.

Comment: @IvanStarostin they are the same column.

Comment: @Arvo - thanks will give this a try and get back to you.