# Select record with newline character ("\n") from SQL Server in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a record in SQL Server with new line character ("\n") and I need to select the record from C# using `SqlCommand`. This is my SQL statement:

```
select customer_id, customer_name 
from customer 
where customer_id = 'Customer 1\n';
```

The record exists in the database, but when trying to retrieve it using C#, it is not returned. I have tried the below queries and its result:

```
--Return the record
select customer_id, customer_name 
from customer 
where customer_id '%' + char(10) + '%'

--Not returning the record
select customer_id, customer_name  
from customer 
where customer_id char(10) + '%'

select customer_id, customer_name  
from customer  
where customer_id '%' + char(10)
```

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any results if you run the query directly against the database?

Comment: Are you sure there *is* a single terminating newline to begin with? Have you tried using `LIKE 'Customer 1%` to see what gets returned? `\n` is an escape sequense for C-like languages, not SQL or T-SQL anyway.

Comment: Did you try with char(13) also like this response ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3872309

Comment: Perhaps there's *no* extra whitespace. Perhaps the string was loaded from a Windows text file without cleaning, in which case the line terminator is `\r\n`, which needs `CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)`. What do `LEN(customer_name)` and `DATALENGTH(customer_name)` return?

Comment: In any case the real solution is to clean up the data before loading it into the database. If this came from a form, the form should strip surrounding whitespace. If this came from a file, there's a bug that *doesn't* strip the line terminators properly. If for example `\n` is used as a terminator on a DOS-style file, the last field in a CSV may end up containing `\r` (CHR(13))

Comment: The 4 posted queries are invalid unless the `LIKE` operator was omitted by mistake. The two that work expect another character before `\n`, I suspect `\r`. You need to append `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)` BUT a far better solution would be to fix the bug that allowed newlines into the fields in the first place

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @NewLineChar AS CHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
select customer_id,customer_name from customer where customer_id='Customer' + @NewLineChar;
```

Comment: adding a verbal explanation is often helpful